# Un archivo manifest me impide el acceso a internet en Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un problema, el siguiente manifest me impide el acceso a internet en *Android*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.educaapp.toolearning.educaapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Ruleta" />
        <activity android:name=".Preguntas"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Tu app está conectada a internet y no tiene acceso a el?

Comment: Creo que lo que comentas @CarlosHernández es definitivamente el problema.

Answer (score 4):

El archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` no puede restringir el acceso a internet, en realidad es para definir permisos que serán usados por la aplicación, obviamente no tendrás acceso a internet si no esta definido el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

El permiso para permitir conexión a internet no esta definido dentro de los [permisos riesgosos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html?hl=es#normal-dangerous) que debes pedir manual mente en sistemas operativos 6.0+, por lo tanto es suficiente con definir el permiso dentro del `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Esta sería la forma de obtener la conectividad:

```
    ConnectivityManager cm =
 (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

**Tu declaración del permiso es correcta, el problema se puede deber a que no tienes datos o acceso a una red WiFi.**

Aquí la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html).

Answer (score 1):

Como ya se ha dicho, el archivo `manifest.xml` impide de forma implícita lo que no autorizas en él, en caso de que un permiso sea requerido. Es decir, manifest sirve para permitir, no para impedir. Aunque a partir de Android 6 hay algunos permisos considerados peligrosos, los cuales el manifest no puede autorizar per se, sino que se necesita que el usuario los autorice cuando son solicitados, pero no es el caso de la conexión a internet.

En el manifest que muestras la conexión a internet está permitida por esta entrada:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

y la que tienes más abajo:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

ha de servirte **para [verificar que hay conexión a internet](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) disponible antes de lanzar cualquier acción que requiera su uso**.

Por ejemplo:

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Si implementas un código como este, antes de lanzar cualquier cosa que tenga que ver con internet debes preguntar si la variable `isConnected` es verdadera.

Pero... el que esté conectado no significa que el internet funcione. A veces estás conectado a un Wi-Fi pero el internet puede no estar funcionando porque el servidor de tu proveedor está caído. O puedes estar conectado a la red móvil, pero no tener crédito en tu plan para usar la transmisión de datos... Se necesita entonces una comprobación suplementaria que contemple estos casos. Este podría ser el objeto de una pregunta interesante en esSO :)

Answer (score 0):

Si tu app hace uso de la conexión a internet, se debe de declarar en tu archivo AndroidManifest.xml el siguiente permiso:

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```