# App Android que consuma un web service remoto

Tags: android, webservice

soy nuevo en esto, trataré de ser especifico.
Ya tengo el web service publicado en el iis de un windows server 2012, manejo entity framework para acceder a una BD de SQLServer y mediante un webmethod inserto datos en una tabla y al ejecutar el WS de manera local en el explorador si inserta los datos, hasta ahí todo bien pero, al momento de querer hacerlo con android simplemente no hace nada. Ya tengo instalada la libreria ksoap2, he visto sin fin de tutoriales y ninguna resulve la duda de que es lo que me falta por hacer.
Les adjunto mi código android, manejo hilos por la versión de android que uso, de lo contrario truena, es un método que se activa al presionar un botón. gracias de antemano.

```
    public void Cita(View v) {

    Thread nt = new Thread(){

        EditText nombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
        EditText apellido = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtApellido);
        EditText fecha = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFecha);
        EditText empleado = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEmpleado);
        EditText servicio = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtServicio);
        String res;
        @Override
        public void run(){
            String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
            String URL = "http://192.168.1.253/ServidorWeb/SWS.asmx";
            String METHOD_NAME = "AgregarCita";
            String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/AgregarCita";

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            request.addProperty("nombre",nombre.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty("apellido",apellido.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty("fecha",fecha.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty("idEmpleado",Integer.parseInt(empleado.getText().toString()));
            request.addProperty("idServicio",Integer.parseInt(servicio.getText().toString()));


            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            try{
                transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapObject resultado = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
                res = resultado.toString();
                res += "Agregado";
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                res += "Error";
            }catch (XmlPullParserException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                res += "Error2";
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(InsertaCita.this, res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    nt.start();
}
```

[image: servicio]

Dato importante que pasé por alto, independientemente de dar permiso de Internet en el manifest se de be de agregar esto:

```
  ConnectivityManager cm =
```

(ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

```
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Iván!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,  un gran saludo, bienvenido!

Comment: Primeramente debes probar tu WS, en este caso el método "AgregarCita", por lo tanto accede a este url 
http://192.168.1.253/ServidorWeb/SWS.asmx?op=AgregarCita e indicanos que campos usa el método AgregarCita. Si son los mismos que indicas, "nombre, appellido, fecha, idEmpleado, idServicio" realiza una prueba directamente e indicanos que resultado obtienes.

Comment: @Jorgesys Ya adjunté la imagen del web service al ser ejecutado. Al invocar solo regresa un string de insertado: <string>Insertado</string>
Y si lo inserta en la BD que tengo en SQLServer

Comment: Gracias por agregar la actualización, de eso habla el documento [ask], que te parece si tomas unos segundos y realizas el [tour],  y después de esto agrego una respuesta!

Comment: Yo quiero saber si has agregado los permisos necesarios en el manifest y claro importantisimo, el servicio web esta publicado en una dirección IP privada (empieza por 192....) El teléfono donde estas probando tiene acceso a esa IP, me refiero si desde el navegador del teléfono puedes abrir esa misma dirección del servicio web? Estos factores son buenos a considerar. Ahora bien has intentado debuguear? poner un break-point y ver que excepción arroja. O bien si el app se detiene puede ser una excepción no capturada toma en cuenta estas recomendaciones. Tal vez sea útil para encontrar el causante

Comment: Claro @Jorgesys dalo por hecho y muchas gracias.

Comment: @GustavoMora honestamente no se como agregar los permisos en el manifest, podrías explicarme por favor?
El serivico Web ya está publicado y el teléfono donde estoy probando si tiene acceso a esa IP, se muestran los WEBMETHODS que tengo en el WS. En cuanto a debuguear lo haré para revisar que excepción arroja. Gracias por tu apoyo.

Comment: @IvánGonzalez revisa el ejemplo de esta pregunta : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54369/un-archivo-manifest-me-impide-el-acceso-a-internet-en-android/54461#54461

Comment: @Jorgesys Si he implementado el permiso de acceso a internet en el manifest ahora revisaré al ConnectivityManager. Gracias

Comment: @Jorgesys también revisaré lo del casting a SoapObject.

Comment: Cuéntanos si solucionaste el problema o  si tienes una pista de la causa. Una excepción etc...

Comment: @GustavoMora claro, con todo gusto en cuanto lo implemente les responderé, por ahora estoy en la escuela, llegando a casa les mantengo al tanto de lo que pasa con la app. Gracias.

Comment: @GustavoMora ya lo he cambiado el SoapPrimitive por SoapObject y ahora me manda a la excepción de IOException "nullError".

Comment: Pon un break-point antes de hacer la conversion a SoapObject y revisa en tus watchpoints que valor tiene la variable envelope.getResponse()

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, has probado directamente el método "AgregarCita", accediendo al url
http://192.168.1.253/ServidorWeb/SWS.asmx?op=AgregarCita , comentas que obtienes como resultado:

```
 <string>Insertado</string>
```

Por lo tanto podemos determinar que el Web Service esta funcionando correctamente.

Ahora veamos, revisando tu código puedo señalar el problema, `envelope.getResponse()` obtiene un `SoapObject` por lo tanto no debes realizar casting a `SoapPrimitive`:

```
 SoapPrimitive resultado = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
```

Debes cambiar a :

```
 SoapObject resultado = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

Para obtener un `SoapObject` con el resultado de la consulta al Web Service.

---

No esta demás comentarlo pero recuerda dar permisos de internet a tu aplicación, configuralo en el `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```